# how to keep a wet edge applying poly to the floors of a whole house

Tags: polyurethane

My floors are ready for poly. Is it possible to keep a wet edge, when the whole house needs poly, and every room conects to another with 2 diffrent doorways? Every path i can think of to take will end up with me runing in to a dry edge before i can finish a coat.

Comment: If you can get a helper or two, you might be able to plan a route that would let you start in various rooms and meet in the hallway to avoid a wet edge.

Answer (score 2):

I see the pros use a large applicator, specific for floor finishing, looking a lot like a household mop. Not the old stringy style, but a sponge mop, theirs having a cotton pad instead of sponge. This way you can cover a lot of area. If any of the doors have the flooring running across the door rather than running through it, cut along one of the joints in the floor. The lap of the finish will be disguised by that joint. This will give a small bit of relief from the hustle.

If you go this route, have another person to check the progress and quality of your passes with the mop. A 4" brush is used to cut in the edges before "mopping".